# Function executes only one time C

Tags: c

Hi I'm trying to insert String into String in Position N using C . So I developed a function that woks well but the problem is that work one time .
This is my code :

```
char *substring(char *string, int position, int length)
{
   char *pointer;
   int c;

   pointer = (char*) malloc(length+1);

   if( pointer == NULL )
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

   for( c = 0 ; c < length ; c++ )
      *(pointer+c) = *((string+position-1)+c);

   *(pointer+c) = '\0';

   return pointer;
}
void insert_substring(char *a, char *b, int position)
{
   char *f, *e;
   int length;

   length = strlen(a);

   f = substring(a, 1, position - 1 );
   e = substring(a, position, length-position+1);

   strcpy(a, "");
   strcat(a, f);
   free(f);
   strcat(a, b);
   strcat(a, e);
   free(e);

}


int main(void) {



char username[UNLEN+1];
DWORD username_len = UNLEN+1;
GetUserName(username, &username_len);


char msg1 [] ="Good morning mr ";

char msg2 [] ="Good evening mr ";

insert_substring(msg1,username,17);
printf("%s\n",msg1);
insert_substring(msg2,username,17);

printf("%s\n",msg2);



    return 0;
}
```

The program display one message :

> Good morning mr XXXXX

What I remark , that the program doesn't execute any instruction after the second call of insert_substring .And it doesn't display any error . Maybe it is a problem of local variable Used in functions

Comment: What is `UNLEN`?

Comment: The arrays `msg1` and `msg2` are just big enough to fit the strings you initialize them with (plus the terminator of course). Attempting to append to those arrays will write *out of bounds* and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Hmm Sure 17 is right as _length_?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude . Good , but what can i do if i have long Strings in other casz ?

Comment: It is the first time that i know something that @MichaelWalz doesn't have any idea .Cool https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You shouldn't try to stuff these into the stack-allocated arrays but return as `malloc`ated objects.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala but i don't know the lenght of each String . I remark that it works if i use String with 2 or 3 chracter but the stings that use is a sentences . Can I manage the memory and clear it to work after each instruction .I don't care about time of execution

Comment: @MichaelWalz .Any idea ? always : you find a solution for my Problem

Comment: @Amine look at the second comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you seem to be trying to call `Win32 API` functions, get current user's username and print a greeting message based on time of day (but you didn't implement this part yet).

When concatenating two null-terminated strings, you need to make sure that the target buffer has enough space to hold the two strings that you are concatenating.

In your case, you already know your maximum space required to hold username, through the use of `UNLEN` macro.

So you can use a buffer with size: `sizeof(msg1) + UNLEN` alocated through malloc. something like this:

```
char *target_msg1 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(msg1) + UNLEN);
```

You can even use the `lpnSize`parameter of `GetUserName` and allocate as little space as possible, but since you are doing Win32 programming I don't think a couple bytes of memory is much of a concern.

Your code would change like this:

```
strcpy(target_msg1, msg1);
insert_substring(target_msg1,username,17);
printf("%s\n",target_msg1);
```

Comment: The Problem is the manipulation of Strings with big lenght . IMy program contains more than 8 Strings with lenght more than 30 . And when i want to display them .It Displays wrongs value . Look at second comment .

Comment: The length of strings is irrelevant as long as you have enough space in your buffer.